# Is it necessary to perform an fsyncLock in MongoDB before creating a dump with mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

In the [2.6 docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/program/mongodump/) it was explicitly stated that `db.fsyncLock()` should not be used when running `mongodump`:

> Do not use mongodump with db.fsyncLock().

But this information has disappeared since the [3.0 version of the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/program/mongodump/). There is actually no info at all regarding locks in the `mongodump` docs from 3.0.

My guess is that, when using `--oplog` it is not necessary to call `db.fsyncLock()`, but I'm not 100% sure:

> Without --oplog, if there are write operations during the dump
>   operation, the dump will not reflect a single moment in time. Changes
>   made to the database during the update process can affect the output
>   of the backup.

Could you help me here? Is it necessary to perform an fsyncLock in MongoDB before creating a dump with mongodump?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My guess is that, when using --oplog it is not necessary to call db.fsyncLock()

Previously with MongoDB versions before 3.0 you *must not* call `db.fsyncLock()` when doing a `mongodump` and you don't need it now. The warning about not using `fsync` with `mongodump` [was removed at several places at once](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/commit/3b38b3251c4c81234dbb709f0683d0e72d96423c), so that it doesn't look like an oversight but a deliberate change.

The `db.fsyncLock()` documentation states that

> This function locks the database and creates a window for backup operations.

But that's only necessary for [Backup with cp or rsync](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/backups/#back-up-by-copying-underlying-data-files). The [*Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools* Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/) doesn't mention any additional locks and explicity mentions that with the `--oplog` parameter, you'll get a consistent backup:

> Use the `--oplog` option with mongodump to collect the oplog entries to build a point-in-time snapshot of a database within a replica set. With --oplog, mongodump copies all the data from the source database as well as all of the oplog entries from the beginning to the end of the backup procedure. This operation, in conjunction with mongorestore --oplogReplay, allows you to restore a backup that reflects the specific moment in time that corresponds to when mongodump completed creating the dump file.

Conclusion: **No, you don't need to call `db.fsyncLock()`.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
_I don't understand why you think it might be necessary now_ :
Well, if you have a look at the doc for [fsyncLock](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/#definition), it says that `This function locks the database and creates a window for backup operations.`, linking `backup operations` to the [mongodump docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/backups/), what confuses me.

Comment: @Ruben: Ah, I see. But it's only necessary for rudimentary backups with cp or rsync, not for mongodump. I added that.